# What is the best way to "paginate" a loooong SVG file on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, svg

I am facing an interesting problem with SVG and iOS.

I need to render very long SVG files (up to about 5mb large), which hasn't been a problem using UIWebView. I also haven't had a problem scrolling them smoothly with JS, but since I'm waiting on my developer program application to be approved I haven't tested the performance on an actual device.

I'm now trying to achieve a page-turning effect like how the iBooks app flips pages. It doesn't have to be as elaborate and intricate, the gist of the idea is that the next section of the svg will "wipe over" the last.

Reason being, I need both "pages" of content to remain static to ease the reading of the content during the "flipping" process. Scrolling very quickly makes the contents of the SVG difficult to read.

Here is a graphic representation of what I would like to achieve:

```
---------------------------
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|            1            |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
---------------------------

---------------------------
|       |                 |
|       |                 |
|       |                 |
|   2   |         1       |
|       |->               |
|       |                 |
|       /                 |
|      /                  |
---------------------------

---------------------------
|                   |     |
|                   |     |
|                   |     |
|          2        |  1  |
|                   |->   |
|                   |     |
|                   /     |
|                  /      |
---------------------------

---------------------------
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|            2            |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
---------------------------
```

Looking forward to some interesting ideas from you veterans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't rut to such needs, but from what I know, it could be made by two `UIView`s (or any of their subclasses). All you have to do is a custom animation on flip(a simple one if you interested in flip only, a harder one if you need the animation actually to go one with the finger). And of course you'll need to put corresponding part of your file to those views. Actually I would suggest using 3 views, so you'll be able to put content of the next "page" while it still offscreen. That will make your animation smoother.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I think the problem with this approach is that having three views would triple the resource consumption of my app.

I suppose I will need an actual device to test this, but I have a feeling that it would crash the app.

Are there any native ways to render just part of an SVG? Or is UIWebView smart enough to do that already?

Comment: Also, from what I've gathered during my research, UIWebView does not render its contents when it is off-screen, which would make having three views redundant..

Comment: If you want animation you'll have to do it yourself, as UIWebView will just scroll it's content.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think I may have an easier solution working with PDF instead and using the built in transition solutions in UIView.